# Transfer packages from Windows Subsystem to Ubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dpkg

Apologies if this was asked elsewhere, but I haven't found a solution for my exact situation.

I'm trying to transfer the installed packages from my Windows Subsystem for Linux to the dual-boot I just set up for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

To clarify, I am only interested to have the same packages and versions installed in the new dual boot, so I'll have the same functionality that I did before on WSL.

Does anyone know if this is possible at all? If so, what would be a convenient solution?

Comment: The packages can be installed from their repository. Your specific settings can be transferred by copying your home folder. Or what else would you like to do?

Comment: what would be a convenient solution? -- Just install the package in dual booted Ubuntu with `apt` command or Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

1. Make sure everything is 100% up to date in WSL (`apt update && apt upgrade`).
2. Install aptitude in WSL (it's a text-based front-end for APT/dpkg, the package name is `aptitude`) in WSL.
3. Run aptitude interactively in WSL at least one time.
4. Copy the state file from `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates` out to whatever storage you're using to transfer data.
5. On the native Ubuntu install, install aptitude and then copy the file from step 3 into `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates`.
6. Run `aptitude upgrade` on the native Ubuntu install.

Aptitude itself keeps a record of what state all the packages in the system were in last time it was run.  Copying out this single file and putting it on a new system is essentially the simplest way to transfer a package list on a Debian (or Ubuntu) system, since aptitude will try to make sure APT/dpkg states match what aptitude itself has recorded whenever it's run.

Note that your native Ubuntu install will probably already have quite a few packages your existing WSL install did not, be careful to not remove any of these by accident when cleaning things up after step 6 above, as doing so may break your system.